# elasticsearch faceted navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to create a rails app like the one [here](https://github.com/farhan-faruque/RailsPostSearch) on elasticsearch aggregations. I updated it to work with the current elasticsearch 2.3. The javascript works well but the filter returns nothing when I select more that one checkbox. The code different from the app [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails) which does not handle checkboxs. What am I missing?

filter looks like this:

```
  __set_filters = lambda do |key, f|
    @search_definition[:post_filter][:and] ||= []
    @search_definition[:post_filter][:and]  |= [f]

    @search_definition[:aggregations][key.to_sym][:filter][:bool][:must] ||= []
    @search_definition[:aggregations][key.to_sym][:filter][:bool][:must]  |= [f]
  end

if options[:category]
  f = { term: { "categories,name" => options[:category] } }
  __set_filters.(:location, f)
end

if options[:location]
  f = { term: { "location,name" => options[:location] } }
  __set_filters.(:categories, f)
end
```

Comment: Give an example of a category name.  Are their spaces?  Did you use the standard analyzer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using filters can cause a headache when new to Elastic Search because it is seeking an exact match of your input for a specific field however when it first indexes things (especially strings using the standard analyzer if you didnt specify a different one) it will split fields into multiple strings that their docs refer to as tokens. For example indexing a town named "Oyster Bay" without specifying an analyzer will actually break the field into two tokens "Oyster" and "Bay".  If you then try to use a filter on this field and put in "Oyster Bay" it won't see it as an exact match and return it.  I would recommend if you plan on using filters over queries to add "not_analyzed" indexing to those respective fields in your mapping to avoid this issue.

Comment: Very helpful Thanks